# Ubuntu settings icons are missing in gnome

Tags: gnome, icons, 22.04

I installed ubuntu 22.04 two weeks ago. I started using and it's all fine until two weeks.
in one day, i log out and come back. Setting icons are missing.

[image: missing icons photo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstall icons with below command and log out of the system and you're good to go.

Run below command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -S /usr/share/ | sed 's/,//g' | sed 's/: \/usr\/share//g')
```

and logout

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me! You might want to mark your response as an answer.