# Icons in GUIs are all missing textures

Tags: dual-boot, icons

I am currently dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.
Recently my computer froze while I was in Ubuntu, I could move the mouse and nothing else. I had to unplug it. When I restarted, my grub bootloader was corrupted which I fixed with the boot repair utility. But now that I am back in linux, most of the icons that came with ubuntu are gone.
[A picture speaks a thousand words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRJgb.jpg)
So far I have tried (with a restart inbetween):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall adwaita-icon-theme
<reboot>
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop
<reboot>
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
<reboot>
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
<reboot>
```

When I run gnome-control-center, I get missing icon warnings in the console:

> (software-properties-gtk:7558): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:51:02.450: Could not load a pixbuf from /com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru-purple/3.0/assets/check-symbolic.svg.
> This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.

Comment: Possibly related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351607/gtk-warning-could-not-load-a-pixbuf-from-icon-theme

Comment: You should first try reinstalling `adwaita-icon-theme-full` as I think [this package has the icon for your disk drives](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/adwaita-icon-theme-full/filelist#:~:text=/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/devices/drive%2Dharddisk.png). It's listed as `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/devices/drive-harddisk.png` among others.

Comment: Also, are you sure you're using the correct icon theme and what do you mean by missing icons? Are you talking about desktop icons or the individual icons like for the SSD drive? If you're talking about your desktop icons no longer showing on your desktop, you should [make sure desktop icons are enabled](https://www.maketecheasier.com/hide-desktop-icons-ubuntu/#gnome-tweak-tool) (show or hide desktop icons, select show). Also it could be [an extension problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/1406376/167115).

Comment: As for the warning message. Warnings can safely be ignored and are provided as information to help developers.

Comment: This question was quite similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429465/ubuntu-settings-icons-are-missing-in-gnome I entered the command, it reinstalled a lot of packages. Not the smartest way to do it, but it worked.